# Angular2 form field does not toggle on @input variable

Tags: typescript, angular

In Angular2 I have a very simple form:

**Form.ts**

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-form',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <form>

      {{ details }}

      <input type="text" placeholder="name" />
      <input *ngIf="details" type="text" placeholder="details" />
    </form>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class MyForm {

  @Input() details: bool;

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

As shown in this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/GYYlpQtQkAV3II1QD5Uu?p=info), when I toggle the `details` @input via the button, the text changes between true and false.

However the `*ngIf` isn't toggling the textfield at all.

Any thoughts on what I miss here?

**App.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {MyForm} from './form'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <button (click)="toggle()">toggle details</button>
      <my-form details="{{visible}}"></my-form>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [MyForm]
})
export class App {

  visible: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  toggle() {
    this.visible = !this.visible;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the following instead:

```
<my-form [details]="visible"></my-form>
```

instead of

```
<my-form details="{{visible}}"></my-form>
```

This allows to use property binding, i.e. one way binding (by reference). This means that when the provided expression changes, the sub component can see the update.

In your case, you simply intialize the input of the sub component with the value of the expression `visible` using interpolation. But then your sub component won't see updates.

Moreover in your case, you provide a string and not a boolean. Only property binding allows to provide types different than string...

See the working plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/z7rKGb6mLdLNj2jtSlcU?p=preview.

Comment: A small additional question: If I have e.g. 100 instances of my form and want each button to toggle the matching textbox. What is the best practice for this? I have created a Plunkr example at https://plnkr.co/edit/n8TZjpQgjg1YH7TefPkM?p=preview

Comment: "you simply initialize the input of the sub component with the value of the expression visible using interpolation. But then your sub component won't see updates." -- Not true.  The child component will see updates when `{{}}` binding is used.  It's just that `{{template_expression}}` binding always converts the _template_expression_ to a string, then that string result is assigned to the input property.  See Günter's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use instead

```
<my-form [details]="visible"></my-form>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BfC5i4ogYBusYTFUjp7e?p=preview)

```
<my-form details="{{visible}}"></my-form>
```

passes `'true'` to `visible` (stringifies). With `[details]` the unmodified value is passed. Therefore this form has to be used if you want to pass anything different than a `string`.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? (I just upvoted it).  This answer is more correct than Thierry's.